# Select option doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, drop-down-menu

when I want to select an option from 1st dropdown menu it also select option in 2nd dropdown menu.

*need to work dropdown menu separately.

*need to select radio button when click on text from dropdown menu.

Here is a [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/7nnz9Ldu/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your question is that your two dropdowns have same classes this is the cause for your first problem so instead of classes try using id's.

Answer of first question(need to select option from dropdown menu separately) is shown in fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/sbact4hz/

Answer of second question(need to select radio button when click on text from dropdown menu) :-

```
$('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function() {
    var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
    var concept = $(this).text();
    $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
    $('.input-group #search_param').val(param);
    $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked',true);  //OR $(this).find('input[type=radio]').attr('checked','checked');   <----- add this line
});
```

Comment: I would really get rid of the comment in the prop line. Using `prop` is much, much better than `attr`!

Comment: @ThiefMaster...yes but here i m just giving two ways , questioner  can choose any one of them..

Comment: There's not a single advantage in the second way though.

Comment: @ThiefMaster...yes i know .prop() should be used in newest jquery versions that is why in my actual answer its .prop() only ...i m giving .attr() in comment only...

Comment: Thanks @Exception. please give me a solution of my first question.

Comment: @Exception please give me solution for first question.

Comment: it doesn't work properly. @Exception please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699409/select-option-doesnt-work-separately and answer on it. updated question

Comment: @sohag513...my answer is working perfectly as per question given here ...the question whose link you have given above is a separate question..

Answer (score 0):

You have to traverse upwards as your click event is in the hyperlink deepth down.

Your answer to work separately with the dropdowns and select radio is

```
$('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function() {
    var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
    var concept = $(this).text();
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('button > span#search_concept').text(concept);
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
    $('.input-group #search_param').val(param);
});
```

Comment: Yes..we can use 'parent()' like you have shown in your answer but i personally don't like this approach using 'parent()' because then it will stop working if we add another tag or parent for one dropdown leaving other dropdown as it is..

Comment: @Telmo Silva see this question and answer on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699409/select-option-doesnt-work-separately